# How to roll numbers up in Tableau for aggregation?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data structure issue. I have a problem where I need to roll up my data within tableau so that aggregated numbers do not skew in a certain manner.

**Example of current data**

```
ID    Model_Number  Value
123         fff         2
123         ggg         2 
123         hhh         2
123         uuu         2
124         yyy         5
124         qqq         5
124         eee         5
Avg:         NA       3.28
```

**Ideal state of data and aggregation**

```
ID     Value 
123       2
124       5
Avg       3.5
```

As you see since the data is at two different grains the aggregated number (avg) will be different. I would like to roll up my numbers to the distinct value of ID and then calculate my average which will result in a different (correct in my context) aggergated number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one calculated field that could help.

```
{ FIXED [ID] : AVG([Value]) }
```

This will give you the avg value by ID. You can then use a grand total(avg) to get the 3.5

[image]
[image: grand total changed to avg]